# What genre is "Figure 8" by C418?

Tags: identify-this-genre, instrumental, similar-artists

I found a song from C418, and I was wondering what genre it is, and also if you know any songs alike I would appreciate it.

it is called figure 8 by C418

here is the part that I like:
https://youtu.be/XbVIawerVM0?t=139

Edit: If you listen from 2:47 to 3:05, that sort of "hype" in the rhythm and the drop at 5:14, that is what I really liked about the song, if you know any similar songs please do let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds to me to be closest to ["chillwave"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chillwave).

> Chillwave is a music microgenre that emerged in the late 2000s. It is characterized by a faded or dreamy retro pop sound... psychedelic or lo-fi aesthetics,... low-to-moderate tempos, effects processing (especially reverb), and vintage synthesizers...
>
> Chillwave loosely emulates 1980s electropop and engages with notions of memory and nostalgia. It was one of the first music genres to develop primarily through the Internet. The term was coined in 2009 by the satirical blog Hipster Runoff to describe indie acts whose sounds resembled incidental music from 1980s VHS tapes.

Compare [this mix](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=elrClUozj1c) or this genre-defining track, [*Feel it All Around*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S-0TYeg9Rzc) (by Washed Out).

Some other similar genres include [synthwave](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-DSVDcw6iW8), [electronic rock](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xlcywgEMuGI) and [intelligent dnb](https://youtu.be/5yCiVlEHrCc?t=281).

Comment: you are right, @Chris Sunami. the genre you said sounds like it, thanks! I'll try to find some songs that are kind of aggressive and not so chill.

Comment: If this is too "chill," you might try synthwave, minimalist electronica or even drum n' bass instead.  It might also help if you edit your original question to point out which parts of the sample song most appeal to you.

Comment: thanks, I edited the question. maybe I didn’t make myself clear, I didn’t mean chill, but the song you mention is more like relaxed and calm, sort of happy, and the song I mention gives me tan energetic and hype feel with a bit of aggressiveness but not as much as dubstep or rock. ugh, maybe I confused you more haha, hope I made myself clear, cheers!

Comment: I edited my answer to add some other possible genres, with examples, check them out and see if they are closer.

Comment: thanks Chris. Also, if you like those genres you should listen to mirror's edge catalyst Soundtrack, it has some nice songs too similar to the feel I'm talking about and maybe some techno or something like that.